# Crystal Report - First record or second record of a group

Tags: crystal-reports, report, record

I have a one to many records relationship and want to convert it into one to one. Here is the example:

```
a  1
a  2 
b  j
b  p
b  k
b  4
c
d  0
d  1
d  v
d  6
```

and I want to pull the first record of data like the following:

```
a  1
b  j
c  
d  0
```

Also how can I pull the second record of the data like the following?

```
a  2
b  p
c  
d  1
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to take a group for that.
and do `grouping` on the particular field which you wants.

Comment: YOU CAN USE ROW_NUMBER() TO SOLVE IT.